# getting == operator comparison false while comparing reference concatenated with literal with other reference

Tags: java, string-comparison

When I perform the == operator comparison, I'm seeing `false` though I'm expecting the value to be `true`.

Why does this happen?

```
public class String1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //case 1
        String s1="Hello";
        String s2=s1+"Java";
        String s3="HelloJava";
        System.out.println(s2.equals(s3));// true
        System.out.println(s2==s3);// expected True but getting output False  
        System.out.println(s2);
        System.out.println(s3);

        // case 2
        String x = "hello";
        String y = "he" + "llo";
        System.out.println(x == y);// TRUE as exepected
    }

}
```

Comment: The compiler hard-codes the concatenation result only if all Strings involved are constant. You need to make the variables `final` to get that. But I may be completely wrong there and don't really care, because there is no need to ever depend on that. Just use `equals` to compare Strings.

Answer (score 1):

In Java the `==` operator tests reference equality -> same object

`.equals()` tests for value equality

in both of your cases you have different objects (s1, s2, x, y)

Comment: But I am comparing S2 with S3 both have same values as "HelloJava" and when I am checking s2 and s3 with equal to (==) operator ,the result should be True as both are pointing to the same "HelloJava".Can you please explain why S2 and S3 shows false.

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares references (i.e. pointer values) of objects.

In case 2 the compiler can shorten `"he" + "llo"` to `"hello"` as opposed to the first case where the concatination is performed at runtime.

Also string literals are cached in a pool. Thus two occurences of `"hello"` will normally refer to the same object. This is possible because strings are immutable.

Strings follow the same rule as every other object. If you want to compare pointers use `==`, if you want to compare content use `equals`.